# JSON parser works on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, json

I have a requirement where my code extracts information from the url using the json parser. It works perfectly fine on emulator with android 2.2 deployment. But when i deploy them on phone (galaxy y duos(2.3) or S2(4.0)), it does not work giving null pointer exception. Could you please tell why this behavior and what changes to make to work on mobile device.

Comment: Start Internet of your Phone

Comment: Is your application crashed ? If Yes, then please share error and code with us.

Comment: You might want to show the code that result in the NPE, otherwise we only can conclude: 'You have made a mistake...'

Answer (score 2):

I face same problem , try below code

**you should create a custom class from org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory**

**MySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

Call HttpClient

```
HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));



            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, from this code, i understand we are establishing a http connection. But how to get a handler to the first json object??

Comment: you just have to use getNewHttpClient() and class file which I gave in ans instead of DefaultHttpClient()